# t-test or z-test: assume normality or s≈σ?

Tags: t-test, standard-deviation, normality-assumption, z-test

Let's say I have a large sample ($n>30$) with mean $\bar{X}$ and standard deviation $S$. I can calculate only: $T=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$.

- If I want to use **t-test** for a hypothesis, then I have to assume **normality of the population**.
- If I want to use **z-test** for a hypothesis, then I have to assume that $\boldsymbol{s\approx\sigma}$.

**What is the less important assumption?** What test should I do? Should I do t-test, z-test or doesn't matter?

Comment: If I understand what you mean by Z test, it also assumes sampling from a normal distribution (normality of the population).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is very simple.

Regardless of the size $n$ of the normal sample:

- If population standard deviation $\sigma$ is unknown and estimated by the sample standard deviation $S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2},$ then use a t test. Critical value and P-value use Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.
- If population standard deviation $\sigma$ is known, use a z test. Critical value and P-value use the standard normal distribution. [To assume $\sigma \approx S$
  would unnecessarily make this an approximate test.]

**Addendum per comments:** I understand that there is controversy
about the robustness of t tests for more than $n=30$ non-normal observations. This is not the place for an exhaustive
treatise on the topic, but I will show a case where the t statistic does not have a Student's t distribution because data are not
normal. One can quibble about the consequences for particular
applied situations, but not about the distributional facts.

Consider testing $H_0: \mu = 1$ against $H_a: \mu > 1$ at the 5% level of significance. Later we look at the specific alternative
$H_a: \mu = 1.5$ when discussing power. We have $n=31$ observations.

Suppose the observations are from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=1,\sigma=1).$
Then the statistic $T =\frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ is
distributed as $T(\nu = 31-1=30)$ under $H_0.$ Rejecting for $T \ge c = 1.697,$ we have a test at the 5% level.

```
qt(.95, 30)
[1] 1.697261
```

If the 31 observations are from $\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda=1),$ then
the significance level of an incorrect t test is nearer 2.3%.
By contrast, if we observe that $G = \frac{\bar X}{\mu} \sim
\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=31,\mathrm{rate}=31),$ then a
correct test at the 5% level rejects for $G \ge 1.313.$

```
qgamma(.95, 31, 31)
[1] 1.312597
```

These facts are illustrated by the simulation in R below.

```
#significance levels
set.seed(2020)

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
t.norm = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(31,1,1),mu=1,alt="g")$stat)
mean(t.norm >= qt(.95,30))  # prob of false rej
[1] 0.04985   # aprx 0.05   
1 - pt(qt(.95,30), 30)
[1] 0.05

hist(t.norm, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dt(x,30), add=T)
 abline(v = qt(.95,30), col="red", lwd=2)

t.exp = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(31,1),mu=1,alt="g")$stat)
mean(t.exp >= qt(.95,30))   # prob of false rej
[1] 0.02262

hist(t.exp, br=30, prob=T, col="wheat")
 curve(dt(x,31), add=T)
 abline(v = qt(.96,30), col="red", lwd=2)

g.exp = replicate(10^5, mean(rexp(31,1))/1)
mean(g.exp >= qgamma(.95,31,31))   # prob of false rej
[1] 0.0486
1 - pgamma(qgamma(.95, 31, 31), 31, 31)
[1] 0.05

hist(g.exp, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dgamma(x,31,31), add=T)
 abline(v = qgamma(.95,31,31), col="red", lwd=2)

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

In the middle panel below, notice that the density function of
$\mathsf{T}(30)$ is dotted because it does not match the histogram
of the simulated realizations of t statistics from exponential data.
[Also, for exponential data, the null distribution of the correct gamma test is right-skewed, while the null distribution of the incorrect t test is left-skewed.]

[image]

At this point you might say it's a small price to pay that the t test is a little too conservative for exponential data with
true significance level about 2.3% instead of 5%, but more
serious errors arise in considerations of power.

Now let's look at power against the alternative $\mu = 1.5.$
For a t test with normal data, the power is found from a non-central t distribution. The non-centrality parameter is 2.784 and the power
is about 85.9%.

```
ncp = sqrt(31)*(.5)/1; ncp
[1] 2.783882
1 - pt(qt(.95,30), 30, ncp) 
[1] 0.8588956
```

The simulated power of an incorrect t test for exponential data is about $58\%.$ The simulated power for the correct test with
exponential data is about $74.5\%.$ [Under the assumption the exponential population mean is $\mu=1.5,$ the statistic
$\bar X/\mu$ has distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(31, 31/1.5).]$

```
1 - pgamma(qgamma(.95,31,31), 31, 31/1.5)
[1] 0.7474007
```

The following simulation in R illustrates these facts.

```
# Power  
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
t.norm = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(31,1.5,1),mu=1,alt="g")$stat)
mean(t.norm >= qt(.95,30))  # power
[1] 0.85951
ncp = sqrt(31)*(.5)/1
1 - pt(qt(.95,30), 30, ncp) 
[1] 0.8588956

hist(t.norm, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dt(x, 30, ncp), add=T)
 abline(v = qt(.95,30), col="red", lwd=2)

t.exp = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(31,2/3),mu=1,alt="g")$stat)
mean(t.exp >= qt(.95,30))   # power
[1] 0.58397

hist(t.exp, prob=T, col="wheat")
 abline(v = qt(.95,30), col="red", lwd=2)
 curve(dt(x, 30, ncp), add=T, lty="dotted")

g.exp = replicate(10^5, mean(rexp(31,2/3))/1)
mean(g.exp >= qgamma(.95,31,31))   # power
[1] 0.74723
1 - pgamma(qgamma(.95,31,31), 31, 31/1.5)
[1] 0.7474007

hist(g.exp, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = qgamma(.95,31,31), col="red", lwd=2)
 curve(dgamma(x, 31, 31/1.5), add=T)

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

The power of the incorrect t test for exponential data cannot
be obtained from a non-central t distribution (dotted density in
the middle panel). So planning the sample size for an experiment
with exponential data would be quite unreliable using power computations based on t distributions.

[image]

In this demonstration it has been possible to find exact theoretical significance levels and powers for the the appropriate tests and
reasonable simulated values where the t test is used inappropriately. In my view, this is just the 'tip of the iceberg'
of the problems that can arise from pushing the robustness of the
t test too far, and especially from using $n=30$ as a guide---as
seems to be far too widely recommended.

Comment: But many books write this sample > 30 notation to differentiate between Z-test and t-test. Is it wrong justification?

Comment: @Daman when $n>30$ the maximum relative difference between the student t and the normal distribution is less than 5%.  The reason that books make this (arbitrary) rule is so they can don't have to put in dozens of tables at the back of the book for the various degrees of freedom for the t.  When $n>30$ someone decided the error induced by using the z in place of the t was negligible.

Comment: Technically, yes, _Wrong._ However, there may be some pedagogical advantages to delaying a thorough discussion of t tests to later chapters in a textbook. A major disadvantage is that the rule of 30 can be quite misleading and is frequently misused. With increasing available computation, the excuse for creating this confusion becomes increasingly feeble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There are many things that I don't understand in R. I have only few months that I 'm learning this language at my free time. Despite that, I tried to change your code (https://pastebin.com/Tm1tDY09 and https://pastebin.com/u39tHe5S). I used sample of $n=80$, as bit.ly/3hrMDpH suggested. I really believe that your answer-simulation was VERY helpful!!! It is an excellent Christmas present! Thanks! Happy new year!

Comment: Looked at your R code, which seems OK. If you're going to use $n=81,$ then maybe use alternative $\mu_a=1.25$ (exp rate 4/5) to keep powers all from being too large to distinguish. Change `ncp` to match. // Maybe put `n=81` at top of code and use `n` and `n-1` throughout code as approp. Then future changes in sample size trivial. // With larger $n$ exponential works a bit better for t tests. I used $n=31>30$ barely to meet 'above 30' rule. // Glad for your success learning R. Changing existing working code is great practice. // There's much to R, increasing monthly. Never can learn it all.

Comment: @BruceET thanks for your answer! I 'm studying your code. It was very helpful!!!

Answer (score 2):

> If I want to use t-test for a hypothesis, then I have to assume normality of the population.

Not so.  The population is irrelevant (well...not completely, we really only need to assume finite variance and make vague assumptions about the skew, mainly that the population is not "skewed too much". See the [Berry-Esseen Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) for more on how the skew affects the t test through the CLT).  The normality requirement is provided by the Central Limit Theorem.  See this [excellent](https://people.wikimedia.org/%7Ebearloga/notes/comparing-groups/) blog post for more. Additionally, see this rather flippant [blog post](https://dpananos.github.io/posts/2019/08/blog-post-23/) I wrote.

> If I want to use z-test for a hypothesis, then I have to assume that $s\approx\sigma.$

The reason we use the t over the z test is because there is uncertainty introduced by approximating the sample standard deviation.  If we knew $\sigma$ with infinite precision, we would always use a z test.  We never know $\sigma$ with perfect precision so technically we would never use a z test.

That being said, a t distribution becomes almost identical to a standard normal with enough data.  So while we technically can never know $\sigma$ with infinite precision, we can pretend we do anyway and perform a z test with impunity

> What is the less important assumption? What test should I do? Should I do t-test, z-test or doesn't matter?

I would say that with enough data, error introduced by estimating the standard deviation becomes negligible and the normality requirement has been greatly exaggerated or misunderstood.

Comment: If data are not normal the t test may give incorrect P-values, even if the sample size is large enough for $\bar X$ to be nearly normal. It is _only for normal data_ that $\bar X$ and $S$ are stochastically independent, but the definition of the t distribution requires this independence.

Comment: Central Limit Theorem inform us that $\bar{x}$ are normally distributed. T-test needs the population's normality (e.g. http://amzn.to/2L66oqQ or http://bit.ly/38GNOO2). These books and other (e.g. http://bit.ly/3o1c1oD or https://bit.ly/3hrMDpH) inform us that for a big sample (n>80) we don't have to worry about normality. Also there exist the estimation of σ from s for big samples.  The question is: what estimation is safer to assume?

Comment: @BruceET , these books (amzn.to/2L66oqQ and bit.ly/38GNOO2) and these articles (e.g. bit.ly/3o1c1oD or bit.ly/3hrMDpH) claim that population's normality is not so important for large samples (n>80). Also for large samples we can assume $s\approx\sigma$ (e.g. https://bit.ly/34TIIwR). The question is: which approximation is the safiest?

Comment: For normal data, the t-test involves no approximation. For normal data with $\sigma$ known, the z-test involves no approximation. (In some real applications $\sigma$ **is** known. For example, assays of unknown mean performed on devices with known $\sigma.)$ // When data are not nearly normal, it is best to use a test specifically for the type of distribution (e.g., exponential waiting time data, Laplace hydrology data).// When data are not normal and dist'n type is unknown, nonparametric tests (Wilcoxon signed rank test, sign test, permutation tests) may be best.

Comment: I was not able to follow most of your links, but I do not doubt that you can give long lists of references to online blogs and elementary texts (especially texts intended mainly for students in social, admin., and biol. sciences who may have minimal math backgrounds), which make vague, unsubstantiated, or simply incorrect claims exaggerating the robustness of t tests to non-normal data. It is true that t tests perform reasonable well for some data that are 'nearly, but not exactly' normal. But violating assumptions is always risky, and the degree of risk is not always easy to evaluate.

Comment: @BruceET , I don't believe that Journal of the Royal Statistical Society makes vague, unsubstantiated, or incorrect statistical claims. Neither I believe that health scientists have no problem to work with risky statistical assumptions. Maybe you are right and they are wrong, but I want an convincing argument (e.g. a proof or a contradictive simulation to Ratcliffe's). Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You may want to read the Addendum to my answer. It gives a clue why I am not fond of the 'approximations' you support. (I think you may be reading too much into what some of your references say.) // We have quite properly been busted for chatting in comments. I have tried to make my opinion clear and to provide some support. I will not be surprised if others disagree on some practical applications of t tests.